# Exporting the solutions of two ODEs sampled over same set of domain values

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, interpolation

I have two functions `h[r]` and `c[r]` defined by two differentials equation.

```
operh[h_, c_] := h D[D[h, r, r] + 1/r D[h, r] - 1/lc^2 h, r] + m D[c, r]
operc[h_, c_] := 
  cmt h + ξ ((ϕ - H) (1 - ϕ) )/Sqrt[R^2 - r^2] - 
    1/r D[r h (1 + e^2/1680  h^4  (D[c, r])^2 ) D[c, r], r]
```

I numerically solve them with NDSolve (with solution called "s" here under).
Then I plot them with no problem:

```
Plot[h[r] /. s, {r, rleft, rright}, PlotRange -> All, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
Plot[c[r] /. s, {r, rleft, rright}, PlotRange -> All, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

With same rright and rleft.

[image: graph for h]
[image: graph for c]

What I want is a .txt or .csv file with 3 columns, containing `r, h[r]` and `c[r]`. From what I have read on this site I tried:

```
ploth = 
  Plot[h[r] /. s, {r, rleft, rright}, PlotRange -> All, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
pts = Cases[ploth, Line[pts_] :> pts, Infinity][[1]]
Export[SystemDialogInput["FileSave", "filename.csv"], pts]
```

It gave me a list of 157 pairs `{r, h[r]}`. Then I did the same for c:

```
plotc = 
  Plot[c[r] /. s, {r, rleft, rright}, PlotRange -> All, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
pts = Cases[plotc, Line[pts_] :> pts, Infinity][[1]]
Export[SystemDialogInput["FileSave", "filename.csv"], pts]
```

And it gave me a list of 226 pairs `{r, c[r]}`. This is not the same number of data than for h(r), so I can't merge them.

I tried by plotting the two curves on a single graph but it gave me only one of the two data sets.

I also tried to use Table but it gave me an empty list:

```
tableh = Table[{r, ploth}, {r, rleft, rright}]
```

> `{}`

Do you know how to extract `h` and `c` data for common `r` values?

I'm on Mathematica 7.0

Comment: put `h[r] /. s` in the table

Comment: It gives also an empty table

    In[74]:= tableh = Table[h[r] /. s, {r, rleft, rright}]

    Out[74]= {}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An approach to this issue I like is to rely on the fact that `NDSolve` found the solution on the same grid points for both functions in the first place:

a simple example:

```
 sol = First@NDSolve[ {f''[x] + g'[x] + 1 == 0 , g[x] == x^2, f[0] == 0, 
   f'[0] == 1}, {f, g}, {x, 0, 1}];
 Plot[{f[x] /. sol, (g[x] /. sol)}, {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

here we do not actually use the interpolation but extract the grid values:

```
 gridpoints = Flatten[(g /. sol)["Grid"]];
 computeddata = 
    Transpose[{gridpoints, 
              (f /. sol)["ValuesOnGrid"],
              (g /. sol)["ValuesOnGrid"]}];
 ListPlot[{ computeddata[[All, {1, 2}]], computeddata[[All, {1, 3}]]}, 
  Joined -> True, PlotMarkers -> Automatic]
```

[image]

here `computeddata` is a nice array you can simply export with each row `{x,f[x],g[x]}`

An advantage to this is the point spacing is naturally refined as was needed by `NDSolve`

Answer (score 3):

Don't try to extract the data from the plots. Since the plots have different shapes the interpolation functions returned by `NDSolve` were sampled differently by `Plot`, which is why you are getting different numbers of points for the two plots.

Instead, Solve the equations with `NDSolveValue`, which will give you the two interpolation functions directly. Then use `Table` to sample those two functions over the same set of domain points. I would show how this applies to your two ODEs, but I can't since you withheld critical data that I would need to solve them.

#### Update

I have manufactured a simple example that I think you should be able to adapt to your situation.

```
f = NDSolveValue[{y'[x] == Sin[x], y[0] == -1}, y, {x, 0, 2 π}]
g = NDSolveValue[{y'[x] == Cos[x], y[0] == 0}, y, {x, 0, 2 π}]
Plot[{f[x], g[x]}, {x, 0, 2 π}]
```

[image: plot]

```
Table[{x, f[x], g[x]}, {x, 0, 2 π, 2 π/10.}]
```

> ```
> {{0., -1., 0.}, {0.628319, -0.809017, 0.587785}, {1.25664, -0.309017, 0.951056}, 
>  {1.88496, 0.309017, 0.951056}, {2.51327, 0.809017, 0.587785}, {3.14159, 1., 0.}, 
>  {3.76991, 0.809016, -0.587785}, {4.39823, 0.309016, -0.951056}, 
>  {5.02655, -0.309016, -0.951056}, {5.65487, -0.809014, -0.587783}, 
>  {6.28319, -1., 0.}}
> ```

Comment: unfortunately NDSolveValue was introduced in mathematica 9.0

Comment: @jehan In which case you can do f=y/. NDSolve... Or similar